# Проблемы с ботом, написанным на Discord.js. Не переименовывается канал

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, бот

Я написал код, в котором бот обновляет название канала в соответствии с количеством участников. Но вот незадача, он всё вычисляет правильно (проверил), но название канала ни в какую не хочет меняться, причём ошибок нет. Что не так?

```
bot.on('ready', () => {
    //Написание в консоль по возобновлению работы:
    console.log('Магия вновь наполняет меня!');
    //Обновление количества участников в специальном канале:
    setInterval(() => {
        let chanel = bot.guilds.cache.get('815665353069297755').channels.cache.get('830928936950169611');
        let numOfBots = bot.guilds.cache.get('815665353069297755').members.cache.filter(user => user.user.bot).size;
        let members = bot.guilds.cache.get('815665353069297755').members.cache.size - numOfBots;
        chanel.setName(`-волшебников-${members}`);
    }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы упираетесь в рейт лимиты Discord, пытаясь изменять название одного и того же канала слишком часто. Попробуйте изменить интервал на 5 минут, с `1000` на `50000`

- немного подправил Ваш код, `members.cache.filter` передает в функцию `member`, а не `user`, такой подход будет более правильным с точки зрения нейминга. Также, если вы хотите отфильтровать ботов, можно просто использовать `!` при фильтре, что аналогично условию `member.user.bot === false`

```js
bot.on('ready', () => {
    //Написание в консоль по возобновлению работы:
    console.log('Магия вновь наполняет меня!');
    //Обновление количества участников в специальном канале:
    setInterval(() => {
        let channel = bot.guilds.cache.get('815665353069297755').channels.cache.get('830928936950169611');
        let members = bot.guilds.cache.get('815665353069297755').members.cache.filter(member => !member.user.bot).size;
        channel.setName(`-волшебников-${members}`).catch(err => console.log(err))
    }, 50000);
});
```